# two ajax calls in one script, But use one var from the url in the other ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

The title says it all, I have this script here:

```
var contentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

if (window.XDomainRequest) 
    contentType = "text/plain";

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    },
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://crossorigin.me/',
    success: function(json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.Events.length; i++) {
            var Id = json.Events[i].Id;
            debugger;
        }
    },
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://crossorigin.me/' + id + 'apple',
    success: function(json) {
        debugger;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.Events.length; i++) {
            var Id = json.Events[i].Id;
            debugger;
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // console.log(error);
    }
});
```

What im trying to achieve here is to have the var id from the first api call and place it as part of the second?

However it seems to just fall over on itself without giving any errors.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tried putting the second GET in the success function of the first, after `Id` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this

```
$.ajax({
   // some magical parameters
   // ....
   success: function(json){
      var id = something;
      $.ajax({
         // ajax call that uses id
      });
   }
});
```